# Making jQuery tooltip appear when hovering over a div

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-tools, jquery-tooltip

I am struggling to get tooltips to work when I hover over a div. Here is the HTML markup:

```
<div class="booking_step_wrap">
    <h4>Email</h4>
    <div class="booking_step" title="hello"><i class="icon-laptop"></i></div>
 </div>
```

and for the jQuery I have:

```
jQuery(function() {
  jQuery(".booking_step [title]").tooltip();
});
```

and CSS (taken from jQuery tools site):

```
.tooltip {
display:none;
background:black;
font-size:12px;
height:70px;
width:160px;
padding:25px;
color:#eee;
```

}

Currently, nothing happens when I hover over that div, and I can't see why.
[Here](http://www.thedistractionsband.co.uk) is the website in question. The div in question is at the bottom in the contact section (first circle with a laptop icon in it). Any advice would be welcome.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because you have a typo.

Try without space between class and attribute check

```
$(function() {
  jQuery(".booking_step[title]").tooltip();
});
```

Or simply

```
$(function() {
    $( document ).tooltip();
});
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/UQTY2/29)**</kbd>

Comment: I'm afraid neither appeared to work

Comment: Here is an example : http://jsfiddle.net/UQTY2/29/

Comment: Thanks, I can see this is the right answer, it just doesn't want to work on my site. Perhaps there are conflicting codes of something.